# Datatype error when comparing rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- distanceValue: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- timeOfMeasurement: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- EventProcessedUtcTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- latency: interval (nullable = true)
```

And the dataframe looks something like this:

```
distance |timeOfMeasurement           |EventProcessedUtcTime       |latency
---------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------------------
15       |2021-01-04T07:07:45.098+0000|2021-01-04T07:07:45.676+0000|{"months": 0, "days": 0, "microseconds": 578885}
26       |2021-01-04T07:07:46.098+0000|2021-01-04T07:07:46.301+0000|{"months": 0, "days": 0, "microseconds": 203909}
23       |2021-01-04T07:07:47.113+0000|2021-01-04T07:07:47.353+0000|{"months": 0, "days": 0, "microseconds": 240287}
```

When trying to compare the distance with the distance from the previous row

```
import pandas as pd
df['same'] = df.distance.eq(df.distance.shift()) 
    
# OR

import numpy as np
df['same'] = np.where(df.distance == df.distance.shift())
```

I get an error:

> Could not parse datatype: interval

The distance however is integer... Is the value getting mixed up with the latency which is an interval?

Comment: You tagged it with pyspark but you're using pandas functions. Which one are you actually using, spark or pandas?

Comment: I'm working with Azure Databricks and I import a .csv file using:
df = spark.read.format('csv').options(header='true', inferSchema='true').load('/mnt/data/values.csv')

Comment: Your error message is very strange. The code that you ran is totally invalid on a pyspark dataframe, which has no `shift` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `lag` function in Spark:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df = df.withColumn(
    'same',
    F.col('distance') == F.lag('distance').over(Window.orderBy('timeOfMeasurement'))
)
```